# Convert Comma seperated string into columns using MACRO in EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have an excel macro code which should perform an action and return column separated values,
But what am currently getting is comma separeted for example .

[Output Am Getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF3ds.png)

[OutputNeeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C0Ho.png)

Below is macro i used , to get combined result for country column.

```
Function SingleCellExtract(LookupValue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer, Char As String)
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRet As String
    For I = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
        If LookupRange.Cells(I, 1) = LookupValue Then
            If xRet = "" Then
                xRet = LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            Else
                xRet = xRet & "" & LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            End If
        End If
    Next
    SingleCellExtract = Left(xRet, Len(xRet) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: When Excel opens a CSV file the items are separated into columns...

Comment: Is there any way i can convert those comma delimited text in country , to the one i gave in screenshot. @SolarMike

Comment: to split the countries into column, you may benefit from [Split Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) in your macro

Comment: You forgot to include an example of your input, as text, which could be used to reproduce your problem.